# Passing a tuple variable as a parameter to a function

Tags: python, function, tuples

I want to be able to pass the z variable of a tuple of two integers as the parameters to the add function. What must I add to the function call in order to have enough parameters to run properly?   (Python code)

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

print(add(3, 4)) # this line works just fine
z = (3, 4)
print(add(z)) # this line will cause an error
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually want to pass a tuple (which would be 1 parameter: to less), but you may use the unpack operator to unpack all of the tuple members:

```
add(*z)
```